# Randomisation Services iOS (Random bytes conversion to NSString)

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, random

I am trying to generate a random bytes received from the `SecRandomCopyBytes` to a Random String.

```
uint8_t resultBytes[10];
SecRandomCopyBytes(kSecRandomDefault, 10, resultBytes);
```

The resultBytes is shown below.

```
    (uint8_t [10]) resultBytes = ([0] = '\xf5', [1] = '[', [2] =
 '\x0e', [3] = '\xb0', [4] = '\xaf', [5] = '|', 
[6] = '\x13', [7] = '\xfb', [8] = 'r', [9] = '\xb8')
```

If I convert to NSString with ASCII encoding it works but does not work with UTF encoding.

```
NSLog(@"Random Number Results=<%@>",[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:resultBytes length:10 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]);
```

**`Number Results =<õ[°¯|ûr¸>`**

Is the output string correct or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to attempt to convert random bytes to a string since the random bytes don't represent a string.

Comment: Oh, Ok, so I am wrong library to generate a random string.I used this because it cryptographically generates secure random bytes.

Comment: UTF-8 string has to have some conventions to be considered a correct string. Chances are that your random string best case would be ridden with undisplayable characters, worst case would be invalid and would generate an error. Use the random bytes to generate a string yourself with characters you know are ok.